# Regex to check amount is greator then one

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex

```
^(?=.*[1-9])\\d{0,5}(?:\\.\\d{0,2})?$
```

to check amount should be greater then 0 and it can contain maximum five digit before decimal and optional decimal and 2 digits after decimal.
Here `(?=.*[1-9])` is to check there should be latest one occurrence of any digit from `(1-9)` in the string.

But I want modify it to check amount greater then one(1), so I want `(?=.*[1-9])` to check only till the occurrence of the decimal point i.e. 0.1 it should return false.
Other condition should also fulfill.

Note : the count of digits before decimal is not fix, it will very from 1 to 5, so we can't modify it to `(?=.{0,5}[1-9])`

Comment: why do you want to use a regex? Use `>` operator?

Comment: Dear @Uma, I need to use it in JSP, where in input box i'm using dojo.
Anyway anubhava modified as per my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by using this negation based regex:

```
^(?=[^.]*[1-9])\\d{0,5}(?:\\.\\d{0,2})?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kC9jY1/1)

`[^.]*` before `[1-9]` will match any character except decimal point thus not allowing `0.45` as valid number.